# VSTS - Allow external customers create work items and receive notifications on them

Tags: visual-studio, devops

I have two customers that are very close to the dev-team and doing awesome test-work and have great feedback. I would like to add them to the VSTS project but just to be able to add bugs and get feedback if bugs are solved.

Worst case they have access to the 'work' part. But absolutely not to any other part, an no rights to change anything that is outside 'work' of on project level. There seems no way to do that. Please confirm of give suggestions how to actually do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with a bit of integrations:

- Re "just to be able to add bugs"

  You can use [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-what-are-logic-apps) to create a rule that creates a work item in VSTS project when someone, say, creates a card in Trello. Then you can just give access to that Trello board to the customers.

  for example:
  [image]

  Alternatively, you can use ready [Send new Trello cards to Visual Studio Online as work items](https://zapier.com/app/editor/template/4868) integration from Zapper.
- Re "get feedback if bugs are solved"

  Similarly, you can either use "VSTS - When a work item is updated" trigger from Logic apps to send email. Or you can configure notifications in VSTS itself:

  - Go to "Gear" -> "Notifications"
  - Press "+ New" button to create a new one
  - Choose category "Work"  and template "When a work item is updated"
  - Select "Deliver to: Team email address" and use address of some list that customers are subscribed to.
  - Configure filters to react only on specific items.

  for example:
  [image]